Socket IO Node JS server-side functions running multiple times on client emit
First off, I have browsed StackOverflow and read multiple threads about this, but couldn't find the answer.
The problem: Sometimes, when a user clicks a button and thereby emits a message to the server, the server seems to receive that message multiple times and therefore calls a functions multiple times. This way, when a user submits the allInventionsForm (see below) more than 1 point is awarded to a player sometimes.
I hope there's an internet hero out here who can help me solve the issue!
Client-side code:
allInventionsForm.on("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const selectedPlayerId = $("input[name='invention']:checked").val()

    // Prevent submitting if nothing selected
    if (!selectedPlayerId) return

    allInventionsForm.hide()


    socket.emit("awardPoint", selectedPlayerId)
    socket.emit("newRound")
  })

Server-side code:
o.on('connection', connected)


function connected(socket) {
  // console.log(Socket ${socket.id} has connected to the server.)

  /* CLIENT EVENT HANDLERS */
  socket.on("joinRoom", () => { joinRoom(socket) })
  [...]
  socket.on("awardPoint", playerId => { awardPoint(socket, playerId) })
  socket.on("newRound", () => { newRound(socket.roomId) })
}

function awardPoint(socket, playerId) {
  const room = func.getRoomById(socket.roomId)
  room.players[${playerId}].score++
  func.emitToRoom(room, "updatePlayerInfo", room)
}

[...]

